# Multiple remotes in rclone configuration file(s)

Tags: ubuntu

After reading rclone's documentation I can see you add a remote like this

```
#normal space
[my-first-space]
type = s3
env_auth = false
access_key_id = XXXXXXXX
secret_access_key = XXXXXXXX
endpoint = fr1.digitaloceanspaces.com
acl = public-read
```

I want to move files between remotes, for that I need another conf block:

I create a rclone.conf file inside my user's home

1. Can I just add the other one below the first one?
2. How can I indicate rclone which config file to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run the wizard via `rclone config`. It is able to configure multiple remotes within a single config file, and it will place everything correctly. The configuration file has INI-like format:

```
[gd]
type = drive
...

[yd]
type = yandex
...

[uni1]
type = union
upstreams = gd:UCC yd:UCC
create_policy = rand
...
```

2. For all operations you can specify which [config file](https://rclone.org/docs/#config-config-file) you work on with `--config` option. This includes the wizard I mentioned:

```
rclone config --config="/path/to/rclone.conf"
```

(path may be relative).
If you didn't specify any path, it will use its defaults, which is `~/.config/rclone/rclone.conf` (tilda means home directory). See the linked original documentation for details.

As you may specify multiple remotes in a single file, there is no need to have multiple config files in general usage.